# How can I determine places where enemies might spawn during the night?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I barricaded all the entrances in a house at the farm for a night and I thought I'm safe, but zombie dog respawned somewhere, probably in the house or jumped through a window. So before I plan anything more I would like to ask about how to avoid such nasty situations.

How can I determine places where enemies might spawn during the night?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, there are two rules governing the spawning of zombies:

- Zombies will only spawn in locations that are dark
- Zombies will not spawn within a certain radius of a sleeping bag or bed that is owned by a player.

Therefore if you keep your stronghold well-lit you will be free from zombies spawning inside.

Other things to note:

- Crawler zombies can get through one-block gaps, even if they are 1 block above ground level.
- Dogs can get through one block gaps but only at ground level.
- Zombies can bash through unexpected places like if you have a large mine attached to your base, they might be able to break in via a weakness near the surface.
- Zombies can spawn on the roof of your house sometimes depending on where your sleeping bag is. This can let them get in if you have a hole or hatch on your roof. This is especially likely when you trigger a spider zombie scout party (when you see 3 spider zombies lurking fairly close together, shooting one will trigger a horde to spawn).

Comment: I know this is an older post, but I had to comment -- shooting a spider horde scout isn't what triggers a horde -- it's when you get detected by them. I've shot many spider scout zombies, and the others may sense me, but as long as I'm not detected, it's fine. A great use for a sniper/hunting rifle.

Comment: You're correct, however I was never able to take them out without triggering the horde, so props to you if you can do it!

Comment: My technique is that I'll take out the farthest one first, so the others don't see him die... I'm not sure if that's a trigger, but with either the sniper rifle or the crossbow (much trickier) if you can get them while they're far enough away that they don't see you yet, you're golden.